# Exception while thread dump generating using wsadmin on linux

Tags: linux, websphere, wsadmin, thread-dump

I am trying to generate thread dumps using `websphere7` on linux, by trying to execute:

```
$AdminControl invoke Server1 dumpThreads
```

But I am getting this Exception:

> WASX7015E: Exception running command: "$AdminControl invoke Server1 dumpThreads"; exception information:
>    com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: WASX7025E: Error found in String "WebSphere:Server1"; cannot create ObjectName.

Answer (score 2):

$AdminControl invoke command require you to pass in an MBean.

You are passing in a server name instead.

Here is what you need to do:

1. get the server MBean as below: (please substitute the mynode to your nodename)

set s1 [$AdminControl queryNames type=Server,node=mynode,process=server1,*]

2. Then you can use the server1 MBean to invoke the dumpThreads as below:

$AdminControl invoke $s1 dumpThreads

Hope this helps.